# Can nodes in .dts files be set to never be overridden?

Tags: device-tree

I'm working with a programming language that targets Zephyr applications (https://www.lf-lang.org/). (Lingua Franca, or LF for short.) LF requires a timer for its run-time, and we generate a .overlay file to configure it.

When building LF applications, we allow the user to provide .overlay files. However, we would like to ensure the user never overrides the timer Lingua Franca uses for its run-time. Is there a way to do this inside the Devicetree language? If not, do you have any suggestions for a pattern that can be used?